# Replacement for 'setDelegate' in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, delegates, tableview, xcode5, xcode4.5

I'm trying to make a database app for my A level coursework, but I'm unable to get around this problem; I'm learning the database skills from a 4.5 video, and Xcode 5 throws a tantrum when I try to use "set delegate' for my table, is there a way around this?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self Mytableveiw]setDelegate:self]
    [[self mytableveiw] setDataSource:self]

}
```

I'd appreciate any help you  have.

Comment: Did you misstype ```mytableview``` with a capital M when it should be lowercase?

Answer (score 3):

You are misspelling it, change this:

```
[[self Mytableveiw]setDelegate:self]
```

To this:

```
[[self mytableveiw]setDelegate:self]
```

You are using the name of the class, not the variable.

Answer (score 3):

It is not the related to xcode

Replace this

```
[[self Mytableveiw]setDelegate:self]
```

with

```
[[self mytableveiw]setDelegate:self]
```

Comment: This does actually answer the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Offtopic: please only use brackets if you call a method and use the [dot Notation](https://github.com/NYTimes/objective-c-style-guide#dot-notation-syntax) for accessing properties

```
[[self mytableveiw]setDelegate:self]
```

should be:

```
self.mytableveiw.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Either is fine; they're equivalent.  Why should he not use bracket notation?

Comment: because of the available Code Guidelines, and it is easier to read

Comment: That is subjective, and does not answer the OP's question.  What "code guidelines" are you referring to?  Can you include a link?

Comment: and here is a second objc style guide from google: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml?showone=Properties#Properties